# Problema con consultas - sistema de turnos online

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

estoy armando una aplicación de turnos online, pero tengo un problema.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aquí el usuario puede ver sus solicitudes de turnos.
El problema es que al hacer click  ver **(...)**  siempre redirige al turno ID 93

**Controlador:**

```
    public function inicio(){
    
        if (Auth::guest()) {
          return redirect()->route("login");
        }
    
        $config = Configuraciones::findOrFail(0);
       
        $solicitudes = Solicitudes::where('user_id', Auth::User()->id)->orderByDesc('created_at')->take(5)->get();

 // OBTENGO EL ID DE LA SOLICITUD DEL USUARIO LOGEADO
        $solicitud = Solicitudes::where('user_id', Auth::User()->id)->get();
    


// OBTENGO EL ID DEL TURNO RELACIONADO CON EL ID DE LA SOLICITUD
           $eventos = Eventos::where('solicitud_id', $solicitud->$id)->get();
       
       
        return view('solicitudes.inicio',compact('solicitudes','config','eventos'))->with($data);
       }
```

Blade:

```
 @foreach($solicitudes as $solicitud)
                                        @if(Auth::user()->id == $solicitud->user_id)
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{$solicitud->fecha}}</td>
                                            <td>{{$solicitud->hora}}</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                @if($solicitud->estado == '0')
                                                <span class="badge badge-primary">Pendiente</span>
                                                @elseif($solicitud->estado == '1')
                                                <span class="badge badge-success">Aceptada</span>
                                                @elseif($solicitud->estado == '2')
                                                <span class="badge badge-danger">Rechazada</span>
                                                @endif
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                
                                                <div class="dropdown custom-dropdown">
                                                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-more-horizontal"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="1"></circle><circle cx="19" cy="12" r="1"></circle><circle cx="5" cy="12" r="1"></circle></svg>
                                                    </a>

                                                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink1">
                                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/turno/{{$eventos->id}}">Ver</a>
                                                      
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        @endif
                                        @endforeach
```

Intenté usar:

```
$eventos = Eventos::where('solicitud_id', $solicitud->id)->get();
```

pero me da error: **Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.**

Que puedo hacer para obtener la ID del turno correcta? y que no se repita la misma siempre

Comment: Te falta la mitad del código que puede fallar, seguramente sea o como declaras los parámetros en la ruta o como lo obtienes en el método que te esta dando error.

Comment: El problema esta en la linea: $eventos = Eventos::where('solicitud_id', $solicitud->id)->get();   no puedo encontrar el id.  $solicitud->id

Comment: Repito, sin saber como llega $solicitud, no puedo saber si la estas recogiendo bien, si le sobreescribiste algo, o si simplemente tienes la ruta mal definida

Comment: Llega desde aqui $solicitud = Solicitudes::where('user_id', Auth::User()->id)->get();

Comment: ¿Cómo va a variar la solicitud si siempre estas pillando la id del usuario?

Comment: Busco el ID de la solicitud comparando con la id del usuario loggeado. Luego esa id la busco en $eventos y la comparo  y de ahi saco el ID del turno que es lo que busco. nose si me expresé bien

Comment: ya vi tu error, si haces get() sacas una colección, pero si quieres un valor unico tienes que hacer first(). $eventos = Eventos::where('solicitud_id', $solicitud->id)->first();

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema esencialmente es en esta linea:

```
$solicitud = Solicitudes::where('user_id', Auth::User()->id)->get();
```

En esa linea al usar **get()** obtienes una colección te recomiendo llamarla de la siguiente manera:

```
$solicitud = Solicitudes::where('user_id', Auth::User()->id)->first();
```

Así obtienes directamente el objeto y no una colección de objetos para así poder hacer lo que haces en tu linea siguiente:

```
$eventos = Eventos::where('solicitud_id', $solicitud->$id)->get();
```